# svn ignore not working

Tags: svn

Im using SVN at the moment on Mac for iPhone development,and I have accidentally added the build directory to source control, so I thought I would look up how to add folders to the ignore list, and I did find an article on how to do that.

so I ran the command: `svn propedit svn:ignore ./build` as specified here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

Then pico came up as the editor, and I added * to the first and only line of the file.

Then I hit save, but then I run into a step that no-one seems to talk about, the file name of the file that I just edited... what is it?

I have tried ignore.txt, ignore, and others, but everthing I try doesnt add the build directory (and its sub dirs/files) to the ignore list.

How do I do this?

Comment: ah! after some dig, I found that will never working because : svn:ignore is just to: "to filter unversioned files and directories out of commands svn status, svn add, and svn import " http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3 in the end of 1rst paragraph .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set that property to the directory you want the patterns apply to, most likely: `.`

to quote [the doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3):

```
 The solution is to store ignore patterns that are unique to 
 the resources likely to appear in a given directory with the 
 directory itself.
```

so, the command you are after is:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

your editor should open up (pointing at a temporary file somewhere). you can now change the patterns (eg, add a new line with `build` on it) and then save it.

Only unversioned files can be ignored, to remove the added directoy from the repository, after which the ignoring can start, run:

```
svn rm --keep-local build
```

Comment: ok ive just tried that, and I get this in the output of my terminal: `No changes to property 'svn:ignore' on 'build'` and also `No changes to property 'svn:ignore' on '.'`

Comment: what do I put in the temp file that opens up? *?

Comment: did you `svn commit` the added `build` directory already? did you `svn revert build` to revert the adding yet?

Comment: I have committed the build directory once, and no I did not revert anything yet

Comment: i changed my answer a bit to reflect `svn propedit` (i was thinking ``svn propset`). nevertheless: you have to `svn remove build` as well to get rid of the what you have commited already. it is now  part of the history (the repository). if you want to get rid of it COMPLETELY then you would have to `svnadmin dump` the repository and `svndumpfilter` the wrongly commited stuff.

Comment: bah, how freaking annoying, why cant I just tell it to ignore the build directory? the `svn remove build` keeps giving me heaps of errors, probably because the build dir is constantly being removed and rebuilt up again `svn: 'build/Debug-iphonesimulator' is in the way of the resource actually under version control` is one of the errors...

Comment: just telling the client tools (`svn xyz`) to not display something does not make the content commited to the repository go away. stop your build process for a moment, remove the `build` directory completely and make a `svn update` (which checks out the commited `build` directory). then you can `svn remove build`. you could also `svn remove http://..../build` directly on the server, if you know the remote address (`svn info`)

Comment: ok that seemed to work, thanks akira, you'll get the points here :) Although I still think that I should be able to tell my client to igonre a directory easier than that... IMO

Answer (score 2):

Once a directory (or file) is added and committed, it can no longer be ignored.  You need to SVN Delete the folder, then add "build" to the list of ignores for its parent folder.

Comment: I wrote the same in other words but my comment have been delete ... , don't understand why.

svn:ingore is just for unversion files

Comment: @Sérgio Once you have committed a file, you're telling SVN that you want to keep track of it; telling it to ignore the same file doesn't make any sense. (Your comment is still there on the original post.)

Comment: 1. Comment still there but with one negative vote.    
2. "I have accidentally added the build directory to source control", What I am telling you, is that svn:ignore never will work on build directory because is in source control, svn:ignore just work for files that aren't on source control.

Answer (score 1):

`svn propedit` creates a temporary file containing the current value of the property, and opens this temp file in your editor.  You should save the file in place (at the temporary location), not to a new location.  When the editor exits, `svn propedit` will notice that you made changes to the temp file (if you did) and use its contents as the new value of the property.

Comment: well its not working... :( running the command, then opening the temp file, adding * to it (called svn-prop.tmp) the I get the output `No changes to property 'svn:ignore' on 'build'` and also `No changes to property 'svn:ignore' on '.'`